# Opening form in a lookup and records in form gets filtered by a value passed from main form

Tags: forms, axapta, lookup, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a formA which is having a referenceGroup field - `field1`. I need to have a lookup on that field. The lookup form contains referenceGroup fields `field5`, `field6`, `field7`.

I need to pass a value from formA from a referenceGroup field `Field2`, which filters the records in lookup form. `field2` is filled. `field1` is clicked on lookup. Then, based on `field2`, value records to be filtered in lookup.

Can some one help me in this? I tried to create form but i am not able to pass value to the form and filter it and get the lookup.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.axaptapedia.com/Passing_values_between_forms. Basically you can use the Args object to pass parameters between forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not, if possible, achieve this by creating lookup forms, but rather use more standard approach.

I would recommend creating a server static method on the table that serves as a datasource. Take a look at `InventTable::lookupItem()`. The important part is that it is always called on server side and it can be reused in multiple forms in future. Of course, besides passing the reference to the control that performs lookup, you can pass the value from your `field2`, which will be used in building the query.

After that, override your `referenceLookup` (NOT `lookup`) method to call this static method:

```
public Common lookupReference()
{
    return YourTable::lookupYourData(this, field2Value);
}
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185372.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [here](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Lookups) and [here](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Lookup_Form).

Comment: I have added a display method and used it in the grid as Created a StringEdit field and given properties Datasource and datamethod(displaymethodName) .  I am not able to see that field in grid.any help?

Comment: I think it is already another question, try searching for an answer, and if you don't find it, open another question describing your problem in more detail, showing the code in your display method.